# Router on one side of a GRE tunnel not adding OSPF route through the tunnel whilst the router on the other side is

Tags: routing, vpn, ospf, networking, gre

[image]

I have configured GRE tunnel between the Dublin and Carlow routers with the following commands:

```
//Carlow
int tunnel 0 
ip address 172.16.12.1 255.255.255.252
tunnel source s0/0/0
tunnel destination 87.44.50.6

//Dublin
int tunnel 0 
ip address 172.16.12.2 255.255.255.252
tunnel source s0/0/0
tunnel destination 87.44.50.2
```

The tunnel has a network address of 172.16.12.0/30 (Dublin = 172.16.12.2, Carlow = 172.16.12.1).

Pings are successful over the tunnel so I tried to configure OSPF to allow for routing between the LANs.

I used the following commands to configure OSPF:

```
//Carlow 
router ospf 2
network 172.16.12.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
network 87.44.50.24 0.0.0.7 area 0

//Dublin
router ospf 2
network 172.16.12.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
network 87.44.50.16 0.0.0.7 area 0
```

The result from this configuration so far is that:

- On the Carlow router, an OSPF route to 87.44.50.16 has been added via 172.16.12.1 (the tunnel interface on the Dublin router)
- On the Dublin router, no OSPF routes have been added.

I will add in below the running configuration on each router for OSPf

Carlow:

```
router ospf 2
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 172.16.12.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 84.44.50.24 0.0.0.7 area 0
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 87.44.50.4 0.0.0.3 area 0
```

Dublin:

```
router ospf 2
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 172.16.12.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 87.44.50.16 0.0.0.7 area 0
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 87.44.50.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
```

As requested I will add in the full configuration and routing table for each router.

Carlow configuration

```
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
license udi pid CISCO2901/K9 sn FTX1524Z6TY-
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface Tunnel0
 ip address 172.16.12.2 255.255.255.252
 mtu 1476
 tunnel source Serial0/0/0
 tunnel destination 87.44.50.2
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 87.44.50.25 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 87.44.50.6 255.255.255.252
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router ospf 2
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 172.16.12.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 84.44.50.24 0.0.0.7 area 0
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 87.44.50.4 0.0.0.3 area 0
!
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 87.44.50.5 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
end
```

Carlow - routing table

```
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
       i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
       * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
       P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is 87.44.50.5 to network 0.0.0.0

     87.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 5 subnets, 2 masks
C       87.44.50.4/30 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0
L       87.44.50.6/32 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0
O       87.44.50.16/30 [110/1001] via 172.16.12.1, 00:04:36, Tunnel0
C       87.44.50.24/30 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
L       87.44.50.25/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
     172.16.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C       172.16.12.0/30 is directly connected, Tunnel0
L       172.16.12.2/32 is directly connected, Tunnel0
S*   0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 87.44.50.5
```

Dublin - configuration

```
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
license udi pid CISCO2901/K9 sn FTX152479Q8-
license boot module c2900 technology-package securityk9
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface Tunnel0
 ip address 172.16.12.1 255.255.255.252
 mtu 1476
 tunnel source Serial0/0/0
 tunnel destination 87.44.50.6
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 87.44.50.17 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 87.44.50.2 255.255.255.252
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router ospf 2
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 172.16.12.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 87.44.50.16 0.0.0.7 area 0
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 87.44.50.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
!
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 87.44.50.1 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
end
```

Dublin - routing table

```
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
       i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
       * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
       P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is 87.44.50.1 to network 0.0.0.0

     87.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 4 subnets, 2 masks
C       87.44.50.0/30 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0
L       87.44.50.2/32 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0
C       87.44.50.16/30 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
L       87.44.50.17/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
     172.16.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C       172.16.12.0/30 is directly connected, Tunnel0
L       172.16.12.1/32 is directly connected, Tunnel0
S*   0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 87.44.50.1
```

Comment: Fix this line in Carlow OSPF configuration:
network 84.44.50.24 0.0.0.7 area 0
In your case it is best to enable OSPF on each interface instead of using network command to avoid such problems.

Comment: @manishma this fixed the problem, can you explain a bit as to why this worked? What was wrong with doing it the other way? Thanks! This was just practice on a tiny scale because I need to implement it in larger design with a lot more components (all college work) so thanks!